# Find the Minimum value of this expression

Tags: inequality

Let $x,y,z>0$ such that: $x+y+z=1$. Find the minimum value of this expression.

$P=(\frac{x+1}{x})^3.\frac{z^2}{z^2+1}+(\frac{y+1}{y})^3.\frac{x^2}{x^2+1}+(\frac{z+1}{z})^3.\frac{y^2}{y^2+1}$

Answer (score 2):

Using rearrangement inequality:

$$P=\sum_{cyc} \left[\left(\frac{x+1}{x}\right)^3 \frac{z^2}{z^2+1}\right] \ge \sum \left[\left(\frac{x+1}{x}\right)^3 \frac{x^2}{x^2+1}\right] = \sum \frac {(1+x)^3}{x \, (1+x^2)}$$

Noting $f(x) = \dfrac{(1+x)^3}{x \, (1+x^2)}$ is convex in $(0, 1)$, by Jensen's inequality:

$$\frac{P}{3} \ge \frac {(1+\frac13)^3}{\frac13 \, (1+\frac19)} = \frac{32}5$$

So the minimum of $P$ is $\frac{96}5$, achieved when $x=y=z=\frac13$.

Comment: Thanks .... But, can you prove for me this rearrangement inequality ?

Comment: For a general proof, refer http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality.  In this particular case, $x \le y \implies \frac1x \ge \frac 1y \implies (1+\frac1x)^3 \ge (1+\frac1y)^3$ and $\frac1{1+1/x^2} \le \frac1{1+1/y^2}$.  So we can arrange the factors in each term in the opposite direction by replacing $z$ with $x$ and thus get a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

Hint :

use Lagrange multipliers